# What is the use of a private init() member function?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, private

EDIT for more details: this is a school assignment and the private variables/functions of the Time class were given to me already. I have to declare and define a member function which adds two Times together and saves the result in the Time member variable of another class. I'm not sure what the assignment intends me to do with the given init() function.

Say I have a class Time:

```
class Time {

    public:

        Time();

        Time(int hours, int mins, int secs);
        
        // public member functions here
        
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, Time&);


    private:

        int theHour;
        int theMins;
        int theSecs;    
        
        void init(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
};
```

I know one thing I'll have to do when creating a `Time` object from hours/mins/secs values before setting `hours = theHour, mins = theMins, secs = theSecs` is check that the values for hours/mins/secs are valid. However, I already have a constructor `Time(int hours, int mins, int secs);` which I was thinking of defining as follows:

```
Time::Time(int hours, int mins, int secs)
{ 
     if ((hours < 0) || (mins < 0) || (secs < 0) || (hours > 60) || (mins > 60) || (secs > 60))
     { 
          cout << "Illegal time value.\n";
          exit(1)
     }
     hours = theHour;
     mins = theMins;
     secs = theSecs;
}
```

If I already have a constructor to initialise an instance of hours, mins, secs as a time object and check for illegal values, what is the point of the `void init()` function?

Comment: Instead of eusing xit(1) which is a very rude way of terminating a process, consider throwing an [std::invalid_argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument). The private init is a way to have reusable code for various constructors. However you really should use  constructor delegation for that.

Comment: I don't get it, you wrote `init` function and now you do not need it?

Comment: Before delegating constructors were added to the language, this was a common way for constructors to share code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old C++ style. It allows multiple constructors to share code.

Modern C++ would use

```
Time::Time() : Time(0,0,0) { }
```

which reuses the existing 3-argument ctor.

Comment: sorry i'm not sure what you're referring to - the init function or the way I defined the constructor?

Comment: just found this page https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-methods and i know what you mean -- i'm still not sure what to write as the function definition, though? i can't delete it because it was given to me in the assignment.

Comment: @SonjaPleština: Assignment? Sorry to hear that, but your teacher is teaching a 24 year old variant of C++ (1998). That's horribly outdated. The "modern" style (2011) doesn't use `init` anymore. Anyway, in the old style, both constructor bodies call `init`, the default constructor just invents arguments (could be 23:59:59 for instance)